# how to assign a python variable whose name is generated on-the-fly?

Tags: python

Say I want to do the following:

```
name = 1.2
```

The thing is that the literal name of 'name' is provided on-the-fly (it could be 'mike=1.2', 'john=1.2',...)

Hope I explained my question, and thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: This is usually the wrong thing to do.  What do you want to accomplish by this?  There is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: [Similar question posted 10 hours ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510341/how-to-use-list-name-from-string-variable/10514464#10514464)

Comment: @AndrewG. at times people do ask questions because they are curious..we should provide answers to such curiosity and not be all about what should and should not be done...just saying

Comment: @cobie That's why "What do you want to accomplish by this?" is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do

```
globals()['yourvariables'] = variable
```

This adds the variable to the global namespace. I am not going to comment on whether it is a good idea or a bad one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `globals()` or `locals()` depending on the scope needed:

```
>>> globals()['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> foo
'bar'
```

If you're asking this questions, however, it means you're doing something wrong - *generating* variables is essentially a bad idea. You should use structures such as a dictionary for this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how to do this as a dictionary.

```
>>> people = {}
>>> people['mike'] = 1
>>> people['john'] = 2
>>> people['mike']
1
>>> people['john']
2
>>> print people
{'mike': 1, 'john': 2}
```

Also see the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)